Video Stopped working in Jitsi Meet after upgrading the SDK
After upgrading the SDK from version 5.2.0 to 10.1.0 to support Android 14, the video functionality suddenly stopped working when transitioning between apps. Other features, like audio calls, continue to work as expected, but video calls fail to function.
Steps to Reproduce:
Upgrade the SDK from version 5.2.0 to 10.1.0.
Attempt to initiate a video call between two apps.
Observe that the video does not work, although audio and other features function correctly.
Expected Behavior: The video should continue to work seamlessly after the SDK upgrade, just as it did with version 5.2.0.
Actual Behavior: The video stops working when transitioning between apps after the SDK upgrade.
Additional Information:
The issue began only after upgrading to version 10.1.0.
Audio calls and other functionalities remain unaffected.
Request for Help: Any guidance on debugging this issue or insights into potential causes would be greatly appreciated.

Do you see any errors/exceptions happening when trying to initiate a video call? Since you upgraded from version 5.2.0 to 10.1.0 I am assuming a lot has changed. Are you sure you migrated the code correctly? Can you share the code where you initiate a video call?

@tomerpacific Yes, I migrated properly, I have checked all the logs but there is no such kind of error we are getting
